# Product of $T_1$ spaces is $T_1$

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, product-space

I am trying to prove that the product of $T_1$ spaces is also $T_1$. Here is a proof, is it correct?

> $\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}$ are T<sub>1</sub> $\Rightarrow$ $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ is T<sub>1</sub>
>
> **Proof:** Let $\bar{x} = ( x_i ) \neq \bar{y} = (y_i) \in \prod_{i \in I} X_i$
>
> There is an $i_0 \in I$ such that $x_{i_0} \neq y_{i_0} \in X_{i_0}$
>
> $X_{i_0}$ is T<sub>1</sub>, so there exists open sets $U_0,V_0 \subseteq X_{i_0}$ such that $x_{i_0} \in U_0 \setminus V_0$, $y_{i_0} \in V_0 \setminus U_0$.
>
> Define $U,V \subseteq \prod_{i \in I} X_i$:
>   $$U_j = \begin{cases}
> X_j, &j \neq i_0 \\
> U_0, &j = i_0
> \end{cases}
> \qquad
> V_j = \begin{cases}
> X_j, &j \neq i_0 \\
> V_0, &j = i_0\end{cases}$$
>
> $U,V$ are open in $\prod_{i \in I}X_i$ by definition, and $\bar{x} \in U \setminus V$, $\bar{y} \in V \setminus U$.

([original image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4IrB.png))

Comment: Thanks, looks good.  Is there a specific step you are concerned about?

Comment: For information about formatting mathematics on this site, please refer to [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348).

Answer (score 10):

Generally, for any family of spaces $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ and any family of subspaces $A_i\subset X_i$, $i\in I$ one has
$$\overline{\prod_i A_i}=\prod_i \overline{A_i}$$
in particular, the product of any family of $T_1$-spaces is $T_1$, as all one point sets will be closed.