# Singletons closed in infinite T1 Product Topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, separation-axioms

[Similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870702/product-of-t1-spaces-is-t1), but I think the question I'm asking isn't covered]

This is part of a problem in section 9.2 of S. Morris's "Topology Without Tears".

I'm confused about  the following construction:

Let $(X_{i}, \tau_{i})$ be $T1$ $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, the product space $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}(X_i, \tau_i)$ should also be $T1$.

In a $T1$ space, all singletons [i.e., points of the form $(a_1,...,a_n,...)$] are closed.

Hence, the complement of a singleton is open.

(**)Thus, the complement of a singleton in this space is of the form $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}O_i$ where $O_i\in \tau_i$ and $O_i\not= X_i$.

Question:  Shouldn't this open set be impossible in the Product Topology?

[Edit:  Answer below, thanks to William Elliot.  The problem is with the statement (**).]

Morris defines the Product Topology in such a way that you can't form open sets of the type described in (**).  Specifically, in a basis set there can only be a finite number of factors subsets that are not equal to the entire factor set (i.e., only a finite number of $O_i\not= X_i$).

I understand that we might not be using the product topology in this problem, since it's not the only common topology for infinite products (cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871610/why-are-box-topology-and-product-topology-different-on-infinite-products-of-topo)).

But if that's so, how am I supposed to know when I should be using the Product Topology or some other topology?  Am I supposed to assume the former as a default unless I run into trouble and then switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement is
$\cup_{n \in N} (X_1×...×X_{n-1}×(X_n - \{a_n\})×X_{n+1}×...)$.

Comment: Ohhhh...I see what I was doing.  Thanks!